# How do I climb up a DOM tree to find a parents that has "overflow: hidden" in the css using the .closest() method?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I want to find any element that is using `overflow: hidden` that is being applied to the child.

I am using the `.closest()` function which requires a selector.

How can you specify that selector to include any parent elements that use `overflow: hidden` in the `.css` file?

Ex.

```
const parentElement = this.element?.closest();
```

Comment: @EmielZuurbier thank you... removing my comment then ;)

Comment: The current proposed solution is right, but you should not need such a method. How come you don't know which element it is? How much control do you have on the page? If you are the author, mark this element clearly or even just store it in js if created dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `closest` to select on specific CSS properties, only CSS *selectors* work with it to select the HTML you want.

You'll need to write a function that traverses up the DOM and evaluates every element it passes. Then when it gets a hit it stops and returns you the element with that set property.

With the help of [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) you can get the styles set on an element. Note that this also takes styles into account that are not specifically set in a stylesheet but by the browser.

```js
// Select grand child element.
const grandChild = document.querySelector('.grand-child');

/**
 * Traverse the DOM upwards and checks the computed styles
 * of each element is passes. Compares the value of the 
 * requested property with the passed value and returns 
 * the element if the value is a match
 *
 * @param   {HTMLElement} element Element to start from.
 * @param   {string} property CSS property to research.
 * @param   {string} value Value to compare CSS property value with.
 * @returns {HTMLElement|null}
 */
const findParentWithCSS = (element, property, value) => {
  while(element !== null) {
    const style = window.getComputedStyle(element);
    const propValue = style.getPropertyValue(property);
    if (propValue === value) {
      return element;
    }
    element = element.parentElement;
  }
  return null;
};

const result = findParentWithCSS(grandChild, 'overflow', 'hidden');
console.log(result);
```

```css
.parent {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="grand-parent">
  Grand Parent
  <div class="parent">
    Parent, I have <code>overflow: hidden</code>
    <div class="child">
      Child
      <div class="grand-child">
        Grandchild
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my example, JavaScript logic looks for a child with the specified `overflow hidden` style, starting from the parent specified by the `closest()` method.

```js
var container_box = document.querySelector('.container_box');
var closest_element = container_box.closest('.container');

for (let elem of closest_element.children) {
    if (elem.matches('.container_box')) {
      if (elem.getAttribute('style') == 'overflow: hidden;') {
        console.log(elem);
        elem.setAttribute('style', 'overflow: hidden; background-color: green;');
      };
    }
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container_box">1</div>
  <div class="container_box" style="overflow: hidden;">2</div>
  <div class="container_box">3</div>
  <div class="container_box">4</div>
  <div class="container_box">5</div>
</div>
```